# Substitute only the first delimiter and leave the rest untouched

Tags: shell, unix

I have the file below:

```
sadhun:ganesh:02/02/1990:345
Hari:Prasad:30/05/1989:567
```

I need to replace only the first colon '`:`' with a space and leave the other colons untouched.

I tried in `awk` but was only able to modify all the colons.

Comment: `awk '{sub(/:/," "); print}'`?

Comment: @kev, put that in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sed -i 's/:/ /' input.txt
```

It'll only replace the 1st `:` to `whitespace`.

The `-i` option is for editing file in place.